# Where to ask about particular part of data getting transferred to your computer?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm not really sure on which Stack Exchange site the following question belongs. It certainly has something to do with computer science, but it does not ask about specific algorithms, code or bugs (Stack Overflow), nor is it a purely theoretical question (Theoretical Computer Science) nor is it about "general Computer stuff" (Super User).

Any hints on where to ask this are appreciated.

---

> I'm sure that most of us know, that when you're browsing YouTube you can hover over a video to see some scenes from that video. YouTube is not the only site on the internet that has this feature (unfortunately none of the other popular streaming sites, like Vimeo, Dailymotion, Twitch, etc. have it), so the question is not really specific to YouTube, but rather to the feature itself. Depending on the implementation the hovering can either show you certain scenes in form of pictures or short clips from the video itself.
>
> **My questions is:** When exactly does the data for these short clips/pictures get transferred to your browser. Does it happen when I hover over the video clip? Or do I already get the data for the entire first page when I open the website? Or is there no general rule and each website/browser handles this differently.

Comment: @ArtOfCode If you can provide another example I'd love to replace it. Unfortunately neither: Vimeo, Metacafe, Dailymotion, Veoh nor Twitch have that feature. The point I was trying to make with the example was, that there are other sites and not all of them might be implementing it the same way...

Comment: So... say exactly that, @Sito.

Comment: @ArtOfCode Hope it's better now.

Comment: Much better. Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps it will fit here: https://video.stackexchange.com/ it is a site for video production and media creation, your question is technically about media creation at a push. Make sure to check the help first though.

Comment: @MarkKirby Thanks for the comment, but I'm don't think my question is about the *creation* of the clips that get displayed, more about *when* they are transferred to your machine. I'm not sure if your suggestion would be a got fit for this case..

Answer (score 3):

I think the SE site that would be best suited to your question is Web Apps. While most questions there are simple how-to questions, there are some technical questions that ask about how a specific website works. For example:

- [How does YouTube detect connection speed without testing/using all speeds?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106358/197614)

You should only ask about one website to avoid having your question closed as too broad as the answer is liable to vary from website to website. It’s possible that the answer to a specific question would give you the technique you would need to evaluate other sites for yourself too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will give it a try and see how it goes, depending on the response on that SE (i.e. the question being closed or not) I will accept this answer.

Comment: The referred question is from 2017. Nowadays questions about technologies / algorithms used by web applications are off-topic on [webapps.se]. Actually, there is a custom close reason for those questions.

Comment: @Rubén Thanks for the info, but I’m not convinced that applies for the OP because it’s not internal. Anyone who really knows how to use a browser’s developer tools should be able to determine the answer (there is a tab that shows when different resources load). Thoughts? (Also this close reason was not clearly indicated in the help center so someone should probably raise that issue.)

Comment: If the question could be reworded to ask how to use browser's developer tools, it might be on-topic in [su] and [so], I think.

Comment: @Laurel I think I figured it out through your comment, in Firefox that would be `right click somewhere on the page > Inspect Element`, open the network tab and look at the timeline. Now the question arises what to do with this question? Should I just mark it as answered?